# Gastby Homepage Components Double Rendering on all pages only in Prod (not in local / dev)

Tags: gatsby

I am building a Gatsby site. Everything works fine in Development / Local but when the site gets deployed to Netlify the homepage components below the navbar are getting rendered twice on the homepage and also on all other pages.

When I inspect the prod page, I see everything inside  is also getting rendered out side of the

I cross-checked  and  and Layout has Navbar. Also, this issue is not happening in local. Also on every page, only the homepage components are double rendering, individual page components are not double rendering.

[Gatsby Homepage Double Rendering](https://keylentwebsite.netlify.app/)

**Layout Component**

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
        <KNavbar/>
        <KSideNav />
        {children}
        <Footer />
        <GoTop scrollStepInPx="100" delayInMs="10.50" />
    </RecoilRoot>
  )
 }
 export default Layout
```

**Home Page - Index.js**

```
   const Home = ({data}) => {  
   return (
   <Layout>
    <div className="App">
      <Helmet>
        <title>Keylent Home Page</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Keylent Home Page" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Keylent, keylent" />
      </Helmet>
    </div>
    <MainBanner />
    <OurServices />
    <RecentProjects />
    <Testimonials />
    <Partner />
    <OurBlog />
    <ProjectStartArea />      
   </Layout>
   )
  }
```

Any idea why production has this behavior?

Thanks

--- Code for KSideNav ---

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
import Logo from "./Logo";


 //https://codepen.io/davidmunro/pen/xxxeoOo?editors=0010
 const SidebarNav = styled.nav`
  background:#ffffff;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 81px;
  left: ${({ sidebar }) => (sidebar ? '0' : '-102%')};
  transition: 550ms ease-in-out;
  z-index: 9999;
`;

const SidebarOverLay = styled.div`
  width: 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  position : absolute;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
  left: ${({ sidebaroverlay }) => (sidebaroverlay ? '0' : '-102%')};
  background-color : rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index : 9998;
  transition: 550ms ease-in-out;
`;

 const Sidebar = () =>{
 const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
 // const [sidebaroverlay, setSidebarOverLay] = useState(false);

 const showSidebar = () => {
 setSidebar(!sidebar);
 // setSidebarOverLay(!sidebaroverlay);
 }
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);
  const showCollapsed = i =>{
    if (collapsed === i) {
      setCollapsed(null);
    }
    setCollapsed(i);
  }
  const [collapsedTwo, setCollapsedTwo] = useState(false);
  const showCollapsedTwo = key =>{
    if (collapsedTwo === key) {
      setCollapsedTwo(null);
    }
    setCollapsedTwo(key);
  }

    React.useEffect(() => {
      let elementId = document.getElementById("sideNavbar");
      document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        if (window.scrollY > 0) {
          elementId.classList.add("is-sticky");
        } else {
          elementId.classList.remove("is-sticky");
        }
      });
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
  return (
    <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query KSidebarNav {
        allMarkdownRemark(
         ...
      }
    `}
    render={(data) => (             
    <>
   <div id="sideNavbar" className="navbar-area navbar-style-two         sidenavbar">
            <div className="tarn-nav">
                <div className="container">
                    <nav  className="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                    <Link 
                        to="/" 
                        className="navbar-brand"
                    >
                            <Logo />
                        </Link>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" onClick={showSidebar}>
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
                        </button>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
     <SidebarNav sidebar={sidebar}>
        <ul className="list-group w-100 sidebar-links mb-4">
              
      {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges[0].node.frontmatter.navbaritem.map((item, i) => {
            return (
            <>                   
                 <li className="list-group-item" key={i} onClick={() => showCollapsed(i)}>
                   {item.navbaritemname}
                   <span className="link-icon">
                   {(() => {
                      if (item.navmenuitem){
                          return (
                            <>
                               {collapsed === i  ? <i class="bx bx-minus"></i> : <i class="bx bx-plus"></i>}
                            </>
                          )
                      }
                      
                      return null;
                    })()}
                   </span>
                   <div className="clear-both"></div>
                   {collapsed === i ? (
                      <ul className="list-group sidebar-linksTwo">
                      {item.navmenuitem &&
                       item.navmenuitem.map((itemData, key) => {
                         return (
                           <>
                               <li className="list-group-item" key={key} onClick={() => showCollapsedTwo(key)}>
                                 <Link to={itemData.navmenuitemURL}>
                                   {itemData.navmenuitemname}
                                 </Link>
                                 <span className="link-icon">
                                 {(() => {
                                   if (itemData.navsubmenuitem){
                                       return (
                                         <>
                                            {collapsedTwo === key ? <i class="bx bx-minus"></i> : <i class="bx bx-plus"></i>}
                                         </>
                                       )
                                   }
                                   
                                   return null;
                                 })()}
                                 </span>
                                 <div className="clear-both"></div>
                                 {collapsedTwo === key ? (
                                     <ul className="list-group sidebar-linksThree">
                                      {itemData.navsubmenuitem &&
                                      itemData.navsubmenuitem.map((itemDataTwo, keyTwo) => {
                                        return (
                                          <>
                                              <li className="list-group-item" key={keyTwo}>
                                                <Link to={itemDataTwo.navsubmenuitemurl}>
                                                  {itemDataTwo.navsubmenuitemname}
                                                </Link>
                                              </li>
                                          </>
                                        );
                                      })}
                                   </ul>
                                  ) : null}
                               </li>
                           </>
                         );
                       })}
                     </ul>
                    ) : null} 
                 </li>
               
                {/* <SidebarLink to="#" key={index} onClick={item.subNav && showSubnav}>
                  <div>
                    {item.icon}
                    <SidebarLabel>{item.title}</SidebarLabel>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    {item.subNav && subnav ? item.iconOpened : item.subNav ? item.iconClosed : null}
                  </div>
                </SidebarLink>
                {subnav &&
                  item.subNav.map((itemData, key) => {
                    return (
                      <>
                          <DropdownLink to={itemData.path} key={key}>
                            <div>
                            {itemData.icon}
                            <SidebarLabel>{itemData.title}</SidebarLabel>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              {itemData.subNavTwo && subnavtwo ? itemData.iconOpened : itemData.subNavTwo ? itemData.iconClosed : null}
                            </div>
                          </DropdownLink>
                      </>
                    );
                  })} */}
            </>
          );
          })}
          </ul>
        {/* </SidebarWrap> */}
      </SidebarNav>
      {/* <SidebarOverLay sidebaroverlay={sidebaroverlay} onClick={showSidebar}>
        <button className="navbar-toggler sidebar-close" type="button" onClick={showSidebar}>
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" >X</span>
        </button>
      </SidebarOverLay> */}
    </>
    )}
/>);
}

export default Sidebar;
```

[image: Side by side compare of JS calls before this started to happen]

[image: Side by side comparison of the elements before this started to happen]

Comment: Can you paste the `<RecentProjects>` component for example?

Comment: Ferran,
Found that the KSideNav is doing client-side rendering as it is using styled-components plugin. Not sure what is the workaround here. I pasted the code for KSideNav above.

Comment: Paste the `gatsby-ssr` then, you don't need the SSR to use styled-components

Comment: @FerranBuireu
const React = require("react")
const { RecoilRoot } = require("recoil")

exports.wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      {element}
    </RecoilRoot>
  )
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using `<RecoilRoot>` component in the Server-Side Rendering but if you are using it there, remove it from your `<Layout>` to avoid duplicities.

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
        <KNavbar/>
        <KSideNav />
        {children}
        <Footer />
        <GoTop scrollStepInPx="100" delayInMs="10.50" />
    </>
  )
 }
 export default Layout
```

Replace it for an empty tag (`<>`, or fragment) to keep the structure.

Comment: We purchased a 3rd party UI template that uses Recoil state management for the KNavBar. So to accommodate for it, had to add this in the SSR file. Understand don't need this twice so removed this from <Layout> component.

Comment: Does it fixes the issue?

Comment: No this didn't fix the issue. Just redeployed to Netlify you can see it on the link [Gatsby Homepage Double Rendering](https://keylentwebsite.netlify.app/)

Comment: Is possible that you are using <Layout> onto another component?

Comment: But @Ferran, in that case, different duplicate page components should show on individual pages. I am only having the home page components showing on all pages...

Comment: That's what I'm asking. If your `<Layout>` has a component A, and component B also imports Layout, your component B also has component A

Comment: Hi @Ferran, I searched for references for <Layout> and could not find any other component referencing it. This is only happening on Prod, not in Dev. So I am 100% sure that no other component is referencing <Layout> if not this behavior will also occur in Dev.  Another thing I found is, when I disable Javascript in my browser, the repeating components are not showing anymore on the homepage. The server-rendered static pages are just fine.

Comment: Once JS is disabled in the browser when I inspect DEV tools I can still see the extra HTML tags outside the gatsby <DIV>. It just that they are not rendered.

Comment: Check from which component comes that extra element

Comment: I added some extra screenshots of the JS calls and the extra <div> coming outside the <div id= "__gatsby"> as a side by side compare to the time from 20th Jan after this deploy all following deploys have double rendering. Noticed a new / extra JS Webpack call not sure why this is showing up from 21st Jan. Any idea why? Ia m pretty much stuck here, appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: Do you have any specific webpack configuration?

Comment: The only webpack related plugin I have in package.json is "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all this double rendering is happening due to missing **< ul >** tags around an **< li >** in the Main Navbar hence repeating on all pages. This malformed HTML never caused any UI issues other than making me lose a good few days due to double rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Another reply from Gatsby Support Team:

"Sounds like an issue with SSR. Looks like the site is using styled-components, but not gatsby-plugin-styled-components: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-styled-components/

That's usually the first thing I recommend looking at.

This is a really good post on troubleshooting rehydration issues as well: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/

Thanks for using Gatsby Cloud!"